# How to merge two dex files from command line

Tags: java, android, jar, dex, dx

From last few days I was getting in depth **How actually *android studio* works behind the hood.**

I explored many tools like aapt, dx, dalvikvm and many others.

Now I have a very simple problem. I have a jar file (called `abc.jar` for example) which is about `2.7 MB` and I also have a very small java code in my application.

First i compiled my source code into `.class` files. Then I dexed my `.class` files and `abc.jar` file into `.dex` file.
It took about 40 to 50 secs. But i was able to run the application successfully.

#### Command that I used to dex my source code and abc.jar

`dx --dex --output=classes.dex abc.jar *class_files*`

Now the problem is whenever i modify my code I have to *redex* all the stuff (including the `abc.jar`) which takes years. What I now want is that **Is there anyway by which i have to just dex `abc.jar` once and then whenever i make changes to my code i would just take the *dexed* version of abc.jar and add it to my source code**.

Like *android studio* does. If you add some **external libaries**, at first it takes some time to `dex` those *libaries* but after that whenever you modify your code it does not have to `redex` all the *libaries* from scratch instead it just takes the `pre-dexed` libaries and adds them to the `apk`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please help me I am so fraustated

Comment: `dx` is deprecated and no longer used as it is not compatible with Java 8 code. Instead `d8` is now used.

Comment: Thanks but I have already found a way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after days of research I found a way...

I juts used `d8` as `dx` has been depreciated.

`d8 dexfile1.dex dexfile2.dex`

Output would be `classes.dex`